# When i call reload tableView.reloadData() custom cell property won't change

Tags: swift, uitableview, realm

I have a table view with custom cell that data comes from realm:

```
var Materials: Results<RealmMaterial>!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let realm = RealmService.shared.realm
    Materials = realm.objects(RealmMaterial.self).filter("InspectResult == 0")
}
```

In each cell I have some buttons that properties change with cell information. I handle that like this:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MaterialCell") as! MaterialsTableViewCell
    let myMaterial = Materials[indexPath.row]
    cell.materialCodeLbl.text = myMaterial.Number
    cell.materialDescLbl.text = myMaterial.Desc
    cell.redBtnOutlet.tag = myMaterial.Id
    cell.greenBtnOutlet.tag = myMaterial.Id
    cell.yellowBtnOutlet.tag = myMaterial.Id
    cell.cellView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.cellView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1
    cell.cellView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    cell.cellView.layer.shadowRadius = 10
    cell.cellView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    cell.redBtnOutlet.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    cell.greenBtnOutlet.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    cell.yellowBtnOutlet.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    if myMaterial.InspectResult == 1 {
        cell.greenBtnOutlet.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 137/255, green: 206/255, blue: 75/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.yellowBtnOutlet.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 192/255, green: 192/255, blue: 192/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.redBtnOutlet.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 192/255, green: 192/255, blue: 192/255, alpha: 1)
    }
    else if myMaterial.InspectResult == 2 {
        cell.redBtnOutlet.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 253/255, green: 77/255, blue: 67/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.greenBtnOutlet.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 192/255, green: 192/255, blue: 192/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.yellowBtnOutlet.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 192/255, green: 192/255, blue: 192/255, alpha: 1)
    }
    else if myMaterial.InspectResult == 3 {
        cell.yellowBtnOutlet.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 240/255, green: 192/255, blue: 16/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.greenBtnOutlet.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 192/255, green: 192/255, blue: 192/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.redBtnOutlet.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 192/255, green: 192/255, blue: 192/255, alpha: 1)
    }
    return cell

}
```

But when I reloadData cell's object properties won't change. It seams that `cellForRowAt` dose not execute again and properties comes from Index of cell.
for the first time that data loads, it works fine. but when i reload data it doesn't change again with new data

Comment: **cell.yellowBtnOutlet.backgroundColor** you mean color is not changed ?

Comment: @iOSGeek for the first time that data loads it works fine. but when i reload data it doesn't change again with new data

Comment: can you show where and when you are reloading TableView  ?

Comment: @iOSGeek I have a uiswitch that when it changes i want to filter data from realm : `Materials = realm.objects(RealmMaterial.self).filter("InspectResult == 0")
                    self.tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: Did you checked when you change switch **Is data Filtered ?** and **Do cellForRow called with updated Data or previous data** Try one thing Reload TableView on MainThread **DispatchQueue.main.async { tableView.reloadData() }**

Comment: @iOSGeek Datas change fine just object properties does not change. I test that Reload TableView on MainThread, it doesn't solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are reloading the table view but not actually updating the data.

From your statement

> It seams that cellForRowAt dose not execute again

I imagine that you have not actually confirmed that `cellForRowAt` is not executed, and my guess is that it is being executed, but the `Materials` array has not been updated with your new data.

Ensure that `Materials` has the new data before calling `tableView.reloadData()`.

Comment: Data changes. New Data Comes into Table view but with that previous custom cell properties